# Unable to resolve service for type DBContext while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to implement .net core Identity on an existing system with existing dbcontext. Here is my DbContext class which I made to inherit IdentityDbContext. Basically I want the ASPUsers tables to be in the same database as my application entities. Migration was fine and was able to create the tables successfully, however I am having issues with trying to resolve the dbcontext with the userstore.

DAMDbContext.cs

```
using DAM.Domain.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DAM.Persistence
{
    public class DAMDBContext : IdentityDbContext, IDbContext
    {
        public DAMDBContext(DbContextOptions<DAMDBContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<ApprovalLevel> ApprovalLevels { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApprovalLevelApprover> ApprovalLevelApprovers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AssetAudit> AssetAudit { get; set; }
        ...
```

Startup.cs

```
  services.AddTransient<ICacheProvider, CacheAsideProvider>();
            services.AddTransient<ICacheKeyGenerator, TypePrefixerCacheKeyGenerator>();
            services.AddScoped<IAzureStorageService, AzureStorageService>();
            services.AddScoped<IConversionService, ConversionService>();
            services.AddScoped<IHelperService, HelperService>();
            services.AddScoped<IEmailService, EmailService>();
            services.AddScoped<ITagService, TagService>();

            services.AddMediatR(typeof(GetAssetRequestHandler).Assembly);
           
            services.AddDbContext<IDbContext, DAMDBContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DAMDBConnectionString"),
                sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
                {
                    sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure();
                }));

            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 10;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 3;
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<DAMDBContext>()
              .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
                    
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

AppController.cs

```
private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private IEmailService _emailService;
        private IConfiguration _configuration;

        public AppController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, IEmailService emailService, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _userManager = userManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userManager));
            _signInManager = signInManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(signInManager));
            _emailService = emailService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(emailService));
            _configuration = configuration ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
        }

        // ASP .NET CORE Identity Implementation

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Users/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAppUsers(string id)
        {
            var users = new List<IdentityUser>();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            {
                users = _userManager.Users.ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                users.Add(await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id));
            }

            return Ok(new
            {
                Users = users,
            });
        }
```

Issue is when I use the UserManager DI in my controllers I get this issue:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'DAM.Persistence.DAMDBContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,DAM.Persistence.DAMDBContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim`1[System.String]]'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
```

Any thoughts on what I am lacking/doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Edit: Nevermind, saw what was causing the issue.

Changed this:

```
 services.AddDbContext<IDbContext, DAMDBContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DAMDBConnectionString"),
                sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
                {
                    sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure();
                }));
```

to:

```
 services.AddDbContext<DAMDBContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DAMDBConnectionString"),
                sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
                {
                    sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure();
                }));
```

Turns out IDBContext was messing things up.

Comment: It is because `AddEntityFrameworkStores<DAMDBContext>()` make it requires the `DAMDBContext` type, However, you cast it to the `IDbContext` type.